# Differences in whitespaces between bash script and interactive shell

Tags: bash, newlines, printf, whitespace

Please advice why this happens.

from a Linux bash shell:

```
ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
20406 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
26896 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

I run the follwing

```
str="a b c d"
printf "%s\n"  ` echo $str `
a
b
c
d
```

but from bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
.

str="a b c d"
printf "%s\n"  ` echo $str `
```

it prints:

```
a b c d
```

while the expected results from script should be like this:

```
a
b
c
d
```

What is missing in my bash script? 
Maybe bash ENV, or something like that?

I run also `shopt` command from my bash script and these are the results:

```
  utocd  off
  cdable_vars  off
  cdspell  off
  checkhash  off
  checkjobs  off
  checkwinsize  off
  cmdhist  on
  compat31  off
  compat32  off
  compat40  off
  compat41  off
  direxpand  off
  dirspell  off
  dotglob  off
  execfail  off
  expand_aliases  off
  extdebug  off
  extglob  off
  extquote  on
  failglob  off
  force_fignore  on
  globstar  off
  gnu_errfmt  off
  histappend  off
  histreedit  off
  histverify  off
  hostcomplete  on
  huponexit  off
  interactive_comments  on
  lastpipe  off
  lithist  off
  login_shell  off
  mailwarn  off
  no_empty_cmd_completion  off
  nocaseglob  off
  nocasematch  off
  nullglob  off
  progcomp  on
  promptvars  on
  restricted_shell  off
  shift_verbose  off
  sourcepath  on
  xpg_echo  off
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. It seems, that the echo part is additionally double-quoted. Please add bash version and the output of `shopt` to the question.

Comment: @jimmij see please my update

Comment: This might be related to this question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676507/printf-example-in-bash-does-not-create-a-newline). Try `echo -e $str` instead and see if that works?

Comment: this not help ( echo -e )

Comment: Did you mess with `IFS` variable, hmm?

Comment: HOO maybe so what need to defined in my bash script ?

Comment: @yael see the answer

Comment: there is **never** any need to do anything like `printf "%s\n" \`echo $str\` `.   There is not even any contrived example where it makes any kind of sense to do that, there is always a better way that isn't crazy.  e.g. just use `printf "%s\n" $str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior only in two cases:

1. double-quoted command substitution:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   str="a b c d"
   printf "%s\n"  "`echo $str`"
   ```
2. or changed Internal Field Separator (`IFS` variable), e.g.:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   IFS=,
   str="a b c d"
   printf "%s\n" `echo $str`
   ```

In both cases output is

```
$ ./test.sh
a b c d
```

To repair first case just remove the quotes, and to restore `IFS` just set it to the default value somewhere above command substitution.

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

---

#### A little bit of explanation why the output is different when `IFS` changed and what does it have in common with double-quotes?

Lets start from the end:

```
printf "%s\n" a b c d
```

is obviously different than

```
printf "%s\n" 'a b c d'
```

In the first case we have four separate words, and `printf` output them one by one adding new line to them. In the second case the whole `a b c d` is treated as a single word and `printf` just output it as such to the terminal. And now should be obvious that the output of `` `echo $str` `` is treated as a single word when additionally double-quoted.

Now is where `IFS` starts to play a role. Namely, tt is used to split words after expansions, so with default `IFS=$' \t\n'` the expression `echo a b c d` outputs `a b c d`, but with `IFS=,` it becomes `'a b c d'` - a single world, although quotes were not used explicitly. One can check that more clearly without variable:

```
$ IFS=,
$ printf "%s\n"  `echo a b c d`
a b c d

$ IFS=$' \t\n'
$ printf "%s\n"  `echo a b c d`
a
b
c
d
```

---

As a final note: it is better to use a `$()` form of command substitution, not backticks, but that's different topic.

Comment: well done its works